# Landscape Orientation not working

Tags: objective-c

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES; 
}
```

I use this snippet for rotation.I am using image view and scroll view in that view.how to rotate that view...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In what Class do you use that code?

Answer (score 0):

First set

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation { return YES; }`
```

in mainView controller then is work's for other controller's

Answer (score 0):

In your info.plist add all the four orientations in UISupportedInterfaceOrientations and set all the four orientations true.